Speech Synthesis Api Language on phone (andriod) doesn't support Spanish?
Hello I have a snipped of code, I generate some speech based on my element data-audio. Everything works fine, except on mobile phone where the language is "English" even though I set it in Spanish.
So I've done some research and found that maybe the language is not supported or the English language is set by default.
I would like to know if you have a solution for me please? I share with you my javascript code.
As you can see I put the default language in Spanish, but it still doesn't work, so I might need your help. Thank you in advance!
const audioBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".audio-trigger-button");

// Variable to hold the currently playing utterance
let currentUtterance = null;
let isPlaying = false;

// Function to hide all play buttons
function hideAllPlayButtons() {
  audioBlocks.forEach((audioBlock) => {
    const listenIcon = audioBlock.querySelector(".audio-icon-listen");
    const pauseIcon = audioBlock.querySelector(".audio-icon-pause");
    if (listenIcon) {
      listenIcon.classList.remove("hidden"); // Show listen icon
    }
    if (pauseIcon) {
      pauseIcon.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide pause icon
    }
  });
}

// Function to check available voices
function checkAvailableVoices() {
  const voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  voices.forEach((voice) => {
    console.log(`${voice.name} - ${voice.lang}`);
  });
}

// Call this function when the voices are loaded
speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = checkAvailableVoices;

// Add click event listener to each audio block
audioBlocks.forEach((audioBlock) => {
  audioBlock.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Get the audio text from the data attribute
    const audioText = this.getAttribute("data-audio");

    // Get the icons for play and pause
    const listenIcon = this.querySelector(".audio-icon-listen");
    const pauseIcon = this.querySelector(".audio-icon-pause");

    // Hide all play buttons
    hideAllPlayButtons();

    // Check if the clicked audio block is already playing
    if (currentUtterance && this === currentUtterance.audioBlock) {
      // If the same button is clicked again, toggle between pause and play
      if (isPlaying) {
        window.speechSynthesis.pause();
        isPlaying = false;
        listenIcon.classList.remove("hidden"); // Show listen icon
        pauseIcon.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide pause icon
      } else {
        window.speechSynthesis.resume(); // Resume speaking
        isPlaying = true;
        listenIcon.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide listen icon
        pauseIcon.classList.remove("hidden"); // Show pause icon
      }
      return; // Exit the function to avoid creating a new utterance
    }

    // If there's an active utterance, cancel it
    if (currentUtterance) {
      window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
    }

    // Check for available voices
    const voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    const spanishVoice = voices.find((voice) => voice.lang === "es-ES");

    // Create a new SpeechSynthesisUtterance instance
    currentUtterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(audioText);
    if (spanishVoice) {
      currentUtterance.voice = spanishVoice; // Use the Spanish voice if available
    }
    currentUtterance.lang = "es-ES"; // Set the language for good measure
    currentUtterance.audioBlock = this; // Store reference to the audio block

    // Speak the text
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(currentUtterance);
    isPlaying = true;
    listenIcon.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide listen icon
    pauseIcon.classList.remove("hidden"); // Show pause icon

    // Add event listener for when speech ends
    currentUtterance.onend = function () {
      isPlaying = false;
      listenIcon.classList.remove("hidden"); // Show listen icon
      pauseIcon.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide pause icon
      currentUtterance = null; // Reset currentUtterance
    };

    // Add event listener for when speech is paused
    currentUtterance.onpause = function () {
      isPlaying = false;
      listenIcon.classList.remove("hidden"); // Show listen icon
      pauseIcon.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide pause icon
    };

    // Add event listener for when speech is resumed
    currentUtterance.onresume = function () {
      isPlaying = true;
      listenIcon.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide listen icon
      pauseIcon.classList.remove("hidden"); // Show pause icon
    };
  });
});

// Stop any audio when the page is reloaded
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
  if (currentUtterance) {
    window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
  }
});

